# Solr query with grouping not working

Tags: solr, lucene

The following query works fine:

```
q=field_one:value_one AND -field_two:[* TO *] AND -field_three:[* TO *]
```

However, as soon as I put brackets in there I get no results

```
q=field_one:value_one AND (-field_two:[* TO *] AND -field_three:[* TO *])
```

Aren't these two queries equivalent?

Thanks all

*Dave*

NB:  I'm doing this as I need to combine more 'AND's with 'OR's; rather than just because I like brackets.

Comment: OK... might be that the brackets denote the contents as the argument to a function?  if that were the case though, wouldn't the parser fail completely as there's no function name?

Comment: According to this : https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Grouping is seems that the brackets are the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the boolean around a bit I have something that works.

```
q=field_one:value_one AND -(field_two:[* TO *] OR field_three:[* TO *])
```

gives the same results as the original query with no brackets.

No idea why Solr is so picky about the other syntax though.  Seems a little bizarre to me.

Comment: The reason why the syntax in the second case doesn't work is that you are creating a subquery which matches nothing.  (-field_two:[* TO *] AND -field_three:[* TO *]).  You tell it what to discard, but don't give it anything to include in there, and so it gets nothing.  In the syntax in your answer, you give a subquery that matches everything with a value in field_two or field_three, then eliminate them from the results acquired from field_one:value_one

Comment: Hi @femtoRgon, thanks for replying.  i does look like that but that's the only syntax I've found to search for a missing field.  `-field[* TO *]` will return all documents which don't have a field called "field".